# Excel compare data and import

Tags: excel, import

I am not an Excel guy but need to do something here which I think is possible, which is to get the price based on matching SKU

So I have

---

### | SKU1 | PRICE1 | SKU2 | PRICE2 |

### | 11   |  ............  | 22   | 100    |

### | 22   |  ............  | 33   | 120    |

### | 33   |  ............  | 44   | 130    |

and I need the result

---

### | SKU1 | PRICE1 |

### | 11   | empty  |

### | 22   | 100    |

### | 33   | 120    |

I have =INDEX(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$2493,MATCH(1,IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$2493=Sheet1!$B4,IF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$2493=Sheet1!$C4,1)),0))
which I believe does the trick but can't really translate to my needs

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula in B2 and copy it down the B column

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$C$2:$D$4, 2,FALSE),"")
```